# can we install IPA on iPhone codesigned with app store provisioning profile?

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, code-signing, provisioning-profile

I am facing issue while installing my IPA file on iPhone code signed with an app store profile.
can we install IPA on iPhone codesigned with app store provisioning profile?

Comment: NO, you will need AdhocProfile for that which contains devices information.

Comment: iPhonic, I have been installing IPAs codesigned with app store profile on my iOs device. It suddenly stopped working and its not working any more. My personal thinking is we cant install but it has been working, am quite confused.